# Can I store a c++ binary file in iCloud?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, icloud

I have an ios game mostly written in C++  which stores its game data in the standard c++ binary format. I would like to add iCloud support but I'm not sure if i can upload this kind of files to iCloud.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud documents of your app or game can have any internal format you want - you don't have to use the NSDocument class.

Note that iCloud backups are not the same as iCloud Documents. Putting user data into the Documents folder will cause it to be backed up to iCloud as part of the device backup but will NOT cause it to be synced to other devices. For that you need to use the [iCloud APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH12-SW47) to correctly coordinate the syncing process.

You can either save non-specific data that will be treated as a single item or "Documents" that users can delete one by one, when, for example, they are running out of space. You can see how this works by clicking "Manage" in the iCloud preferences.

If the data you need to store is not too big (a few kilobytes) I would suggest looking at the [key-value store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7-SW9) as well, which is MUCH simpler than the documents API. It is possible to store binary data there using NSData. The limit for the key-value storage has been recently raised to 1MB and 1024 keys.

Comment: Oh, that's how I thought it worked. Pretty clear answer, thanks..
The iCloud API talks about tranfering Documents, but can i still transfer any kind of data file? (in this case c++ binary files)

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Any file in the Documents folder of your application will be backed up on iCloud.

If this file cannot be recreated otherwise (for example it is a savegame, not a cache file), then I see no problem.

The documentation states:

> Put user data in the /Documents/. User data is any
>   data that cannot be recreated by your app, such as user documents and
>   other user-generated content.

...

> Every file or file package located in the Documents subdirectory (or
>   one of its subdirectories) is presented to the user (via the iCloud UI
>   in OS X and iOS) as a separate document that can be deleted
>   individually.

(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: My game already saves its game data in the Documents folder, so do you mean the user can still back up the data manually? I thought there was a separate "remote" directory for icloud apps

Comment: Typically, any file in the document folder, unless marked by the com.apple.MobileBackup attribute, can be backed up on iCloud. I have updated my answer to include another interesting part of the documentation.